# BSurfaces doesn't work anymore

Tags: modeling, add-on, error

Whenever I try to use the **BSurfaces addon** I can't add a surface, all I get is an error saying

> The selection isn't valid

it was working on one file, but it never worked on anything else since. What did I do wrong?

I am using **Blender 3.4.1**

This has been killing me for days and I really want to do repto again.

I have spent hours searching for the answer but nothing comes up.

Please tell me if there's something I'm supposed to do first.

Comment: I've never used it before, but having had a quick look at [this](https://youtu.be/_33KN56zvq0) tutorial to see how it's used, it seems to work fine in 3.4.1 here. How exactly are you trying to use it and can you add an image of your screen? (Window > Save Screenshot in Blender and then add the image to your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post ).

Comment: Apparently it works when I do initialize in edit mode instead of object mode

Comment: Nevermind it gave me the same error again, plus it keeps freeze blender.

Comment: It started working again. I'm unsure what I am doing wrong exactly

Comment: Can't help unless you show a screenshot and/or share your Blend file.

Comment: I figured it out, I have to draw 2 annotation lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this answer to close this

Comment: Hi, @BeeAPotato.. It's  good you want to tie up loose ends, but part of the function of SE sites is to be a useful archive to others. 'This answer' isn't one, yet. Could you just expand on your discoveries in the comments to make this post self-contained, please? Then it will be more helpful to others, in future.